# Model starts off stronger than SOTA, but doesn't maintain advantage

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, convergence, accuracy

In general, what could cause a Neural Network to start with better results than a similar model, but then lose it's advantage after a few epochs ?

If a NN starts off about 10% better than a similar one, what could cause them to converge at the same accuracy ?

Thanks
[image]